# external css and @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

all. I've referenced SO often and appreciate the community and expertise. Great site! I'm a noob member, so bear with me.

PROBLEM: embedded files not loaded/displayed

ROOT DIR has two dirs: plugins  and  project

plugins has files  mycss.css and 4 font files (2 woff, 2 ttf)

mycss.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ALG';
  src: url('ALGbvs.woff') format('woff'),
       url('ALGbvs.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BVS';
  src: url('BitstreamVeraSans.woff') format('woff'),
       url('BitstreamVeraSans.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

index.html  contains (excerpts)

```
<head>
...
<!-- font-family: ALG and BVS -->
<link href="../plugins/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
<style>
body {
font-family: ALG;
  background-color: #F9EFE2;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
```

I thought I was referencing the css file and the fonts correctly, but they are not loaded/displayed in the body. What am I missing? Thanks for all reads and replies.

Comment: Isn't the whole CSS file loaded correctly? Or only the fonts?

Comment: The rest of the css loads and functions properly... except the fonts..

Comment: Which browsers did you check?

Comment: @dph777 I am having the same issue. It seems that the browser can't load, or ignores the font-face rules coming from external style sheets. It worked for me calling the fonts directly from the html file.
Any of the "answers" here are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use **@font-face** with more generalize way like,

use this font-face generator tool to generate font-face files for all major browsers [Font-Face Generator](http://www.flaticon.com/font-face)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "ALG";
    src: url("myfont/ALGbvs.eot");
    src: url("myfont/ALGbvs.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("myfont/ALGbvs.woff") format("woff"),
         url("myfont/ALGbvs.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("myfont/ALGbvs.svg#ALG") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then check that you are mentioning font file paths correctly, let's assume your folder for all fonts say '**myfont**' is in same folder where you have saved your css file.

Then your **body** tag will be like,

```
body {
    font-family: "ALG";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and @BillyNate. **PLEASE NOTE:** In the directory scenario: **root/project/index.html** and **root/plugins(folder with css and fonts)** , when using **<link href="../plugins/mycss.css" ...etc...>** AMPfont-face in a css file located as described does not appear to work in Firefox 47.0.1 , but does work in Chrome 51, IE 11, and Opera 38.

Comment: EDIT: I found that the Firefox exception above only applies to developing on a _local machine_. When **uploaded to a server**, the directory scenario above works on all current major browsers.

Answer (score -2):

You missed to define source in your css. Add full font url location like this:

@font-face {src: url("../plugins/ALGbvs.ttf");}

Comment: This was intentional. `src` can take comma separated urls, where it uses the first font-type that the browser supports. See some [examples](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)